# How to configure a conditional type based on value of a property?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a number of `Item` objects and a method that processes them. The issue is that some Items could potentially have certain properties that others don't.

```js
type ItemType = 'ApiGateway' | 'ApiGatewayEndpoint' | 'ApiGatewayMethod';

export default interface Item {
    ref?: string;
    position: Position;
    type: ItemType;
    children?: Item[];
}

function process(item: Item) {...}
```

Now, let's say I want to create a separate interface `ApiGatewayMethodItem` (that extends `Item`) that has an additional string property called 'method' representing whether it's a GET or POST or something else. Is there a way I can type it in such a way that as soon as I type `process({type: 'ApiGatewayMethod'})` tsc will start complaining about the missing property `method` ? I understand that TS has a pretty good support for the "conditional types", but I haven't used them before and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around them...

So let's say I have the interface

```
interface ApiGatewayMethodItem extends Omit<Item, 'type'> {
    type: 'ApiGatewayMethod';
    method: string;
}
```

now when I call the `process` function, I need the compiler to complain that the `method` property is missing when I don't specify it, but specify the type `ApiGatewayMethod`

Comment: Do you want all `Item`s to have the method property? Or only the `ApiGatewayMethodItem`?

Comment: no. only ApiGatewayMethodItem will have the property `method`. Then I'm gonna have the `ApiGatewayEndpointItem` that will not have the property `method`, but will have the `path` for instance. I know that I'm supposed to use the coditional types on my process function (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) but the docs is fairly difficult to decipher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your item type with only the 2 ItemTypes that doesn't have the property 'method'. Then add the property 'method' only to the type 'ApiGatewayMethodItem'

```
type ItemType = 'ApiGateway' | 'ApiGatewayEndpoint';

export default interface DefaultItem {
    ref?: string;
    position: Position;
    type: ItemType;
    children?: DefaultItem[];
}

interface ApiGatewayMethodItem extends Omit<DefaultItem, 'type'> {
    type: 'ApiGatewayMethod';
    method: string;
}

type Item = DefaultItem | ApiGatewayMethodItem;

function process(item: Item) {

}

process ({
    type: 'ApiGatewayMethod',
    position: null
})
```

Comment: did I explain the question wrong? Everyone gives me the same solution that is wrong... if I call `process({type: 'ApiGatewayMethod'})` that does not cause any compilation problem due to missing `method` and this is what I want to get with the conditional types (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clearer. The code gives you a compilation error now because "method" is missing

Comment: I guess I missed it. It seems to work nicely! thank you!

Comment: No problem! And thanks for asking this question. Didn't know anything about "Omit" Typescript has many concepts for defining types.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Item` a union type, and define an interface which holds the properties which are common to all items:

```js
export default interface CommonItemProperties {
    ref?: string;
    position: Position;
    children?: Item[];
}

interface ApiGatewayMethodItem extends CommonItemProperties {
    type: 'ApiGatewayMethod';
    method: 'GET' | 'POST';
}

interface ApiGatewayEndpointItem extends CommonItemProperties {
  type: 'ApiGatewayEndpoint';
  path: string;
}

type Item = ApiGatewayEndpointItem | ApiGatewayMethodItem;

function process(item: Item) {
  switch (item.type) {
    case ('ApiGatewayMethod'):
      return item.method; // this is not a type error - typescript 'knows' the item is a ApiGatewayMethodItem
    case ('ApiGatewayEndpoint'):
      return item.path;   // this is not a type error - typescript 'knows' the item is a ApiGatewayEndpointItem
  }
}
```

The `switch` statement is just an example of how typescript can determine the type of item you've passed in based on a check against `type`.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote? If this doesn't answer the question I'd be glad to know why so that I can provide further explanation

Comment: not my downvote, but this is not what the question is about. The conditional types in TS are there for a reason. I'm looking to get a compilation time error upon missing property, not just to get it to work

Comment: @KamilJanowski I think perhaps then we could use some additional information on what it is you do want; we all gave you the same answer; if you only want an `ApiGatewayMethodItem` to be passed into `process`, why would you type it such that an `Item` can be passed in?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by using [discrimated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAq4IHUCWwAWB7ArsALIQ64AmUAvFAOQCCYGA4gIbwDurItUAPnUYt2ELiACiAO3JhcGScF4CGTNp24ky5WgG4AUKEix4yVJhya8lGgCIha0RtJW4iG-r0QAHrIBOwKHl4XwAzVgBjaFcEACFWAGdoAG89KDSoXwgQgH4ALih44F95AHN9dKhZeKwMXEl8gAVcauBayXL08OwMABtyTMk840QAbQBdfQBfPU8fXH9AhQhQiKiTczxCSwoob3hpeOHYhOTUqEMIfOiUSA2CYmcKPWnZvwCg5bDIo43tyj2IAcjnFElAUhULlcTDd0FhsH8OmkEI9yPlCsVJGVnjMLkdqD84X9+ASyFsUR4QvhJOFWnUoORcABlXDInClDbRAAUWEQUMQAEowWcMCEoNyTAA6XFUWz2ERiP7RGyC8GdOrxXA9CASnq4ErixAS1lWfkdabTIA). This way the compiler can figure out which members are available from the `type` field.

```
type ItemTypeWithoutMethod = 'ApiGateway' | 'ApiGatewayEndpoint' | 'ApiGatewayMethod';
type ItemTypeWithMethod = "ApiGatewayMethodItem";

interface ItemBase {
    ref?: string;
    position: Position;
    children?: Item[];
}

interface ItemWithoutMethod extends ItemBase {
  type: ItemTypeWithoutMethod
}

interface ItemWithMethod extends ItemBase {
    type: ItemTypeWithMethod;
    method: string;
}

export type Item = ItemWithMethod | ItemWithoutMethod;

function doSomethingWithItem(item: Item) {
  if (item.type == "ApiGatewayMethodItem") {
    console.log(item.method);
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAq4IHUCWwAWB7ArsALIQ64AmUAvFAOQCCYGA4gIbwDurItUAPnUYt2ELiACiAO3JhcGScF4CGTNp24ky5WgG4AUKEix4yVJhya8lGgCIha0RtJW4iG-r0QAHrIBOwKHl4XwAzVgBjaFcEACFWAGdoAG89KDSoXwgQgH4ALih44F95AHN9dKhZeKwMXEl8gAVcauBayXL08OwMABtyTMk840QAbQBdfQBfPU8fXH9AhQhQiKiTczxCSwoob3hpeOHYhOTUqEMIfOiUSA2CYmcKPWnZvwCg5bDIo43tyj2IAcjnFElAUhULlcTDd0FhsH8OmkEI9yPlCsVJGVnjMLkdqD84X9+ASyFsUR4QvhJOFWnUoORcABlXDInClDbRAAUWEQUMQAEowWcMCEoNyTAA6XFUWz2ERiP7RGyC8GdOrxXA9CASnq4ErixAS1lWfkdabTIA)

Comment: does not solve the problem. `doSomethingWithItem({type: 'ApiGatewayMethod'})` does not cause the compilation failure, while this is what I'm looking for